# Disable options on EnumProperty

Tags: python, interface

Is it possible to disable the selection of options for an EnumProperty?

[image]

For example, I want to be able to disable "Bone Groups" from being selected if there are no bone groups to show.

My EnumProperty is defined as such:

```
    bone_filter_mode: EnumProperty(
        name='Bone Filter',
        items={
            ('NONE', 'None', 'All bones will be exported.'),
            ('BONE_GROUPS', 'Bone Groups', 'Only bones belonging to the selected bone groups and their ancestors will be exported.'),
        }
    )
```

Comment: That's sufficient I suppose. It still would be nice if it was possible to disable buttons so that users knew that certain functionality exists without being able to explicitly use it in certain contexts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a self-contained suggestion that you can iterate from :

```
import bpy

class MyPG(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    bone_filter_mode: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name='Bone Filter',
        items={
            ('NONE', 'None', 'All bones will be exported.'),
            ('BONE_GROUPS', 'Bone Groups', 'Only bones belonging to the selected bone groups and their ancestors will be exported.'),
        },
        default='NONE',
    )


def is_enum_item_available(context, identifier):
    if identifier == "BONE_GROUPS":
        obj = context.active_object
        if not obj.pose or not obj.pose.bone_groups:
            return False
    # elif:  ... you can set up other conditions
    return True

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "data"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object and context.active_object.type == "ARMATURE"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        my_pg = context.scene.my_pg
        items = my_pg.bl_rna.properties["bone_filter_mode"].enum_items_static
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        for item in items:
            # This is the first item of the enum item tuple, eg. "NONE", or "BONE_GROUPS" :
            identifier = item.identifier  
            # This seems overkill but we need individual access to the field layout to disable it :
            item_layout = row.row(align=True)  
            item_layout.prop_enum(my_pg, "bone_filter_mode", identifier)
            item_layout.enabled = is_enum_item_available(context, identifier)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPG)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_pg = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPG)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

1. Retrieve the enum identifiers with `bl_rna.properties["bone_filter_mod"].enum_items_static`
2. Iterate over all these identifiers
3. Use `layout.prop_enum` to draw a single enum item
4. Use custom logic to enable or disable the field

Read the docs :

[Armature](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Armature.html)

[Object Pose](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.pose)

[Pose](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Pose.html)

[EnumProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.EnumProperty.html#bpy.types.EnumProperty.enum_items_static)

[prop_enum](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=prop_enum#bpy.types.UILayout.prop_enum)

Comment: This is great, thank you! There's a lot of hidden functionality in these class variables and not a lot of places to learn about how to use them.

Comment: @ColinBasnett yup especially the `bl_rna` stuff is poorly or not at all documented, unfortunately. One has to rely on examples found on forums and such... You can always print out in the console all the properties of an item with `print(dir(object))` it works with all python objects, classes, etc. Cheers